# How to make a aspxdocumentviewer direction rtl?

Tags: c#, webforms, devexpress, report, documentviewer

My goal is to have a right justified report. So I changed the text align from right to middle center justified because right justified alignment is not supported in document viewer I think. Now my text is justified but the direction is ltr. How to make it rtl?

I tried to set a rtl style for created html from document viewer by css and jquery but it ignores styles.

I am using devexpress report suit 15.2 with asp.net webforms.

How to do it?

Comment: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T359359

Comment: @PouriaSharif Nope. I have made my document viewer RTL but I can not make its xrlabels text set to RTL direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I fount it.

By adding the following code to the aspxdocumentviewer I was able to write css codes for it.

```
<dx:ASPxDocumentViewer ID="ASPxDocumentViewer1" runat="server">
    <ToolbarItems>
        <dx:ReportToolbarButton ItemKind="Search" />
        <dx:ReportToolbarSeparator />
    </ToolbarItems>
    <SettingsReportViewer UseIFrame="false" />
</dx:ASPxDocumentViewer>

<style type="text/css">
    body{
        direction:rtl;
    }
</style>
```